# http to https with virtual hosts

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to move trac to secure connection. I want to use https.

Virtual host file works fine when I put *:80 and comment out ssl engine. Whenever I change it to ssl it doesn't respond via 443.

Any ideas?

I tried this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

   ServerAdmin sandro@h.com
   ServerName trac.domain.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/trac/repos

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/trac.domain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/trac.domain.com.key

   <Directory /var/www/trac/repos>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
   </Directory>

    <Location />
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Trac"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
      Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location />
      SetHandler mod_python
      PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
      PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
      PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /var/www/trac
      PythonOption TracUriRoot /
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I use it, trac is inaccessible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure Apache is listening on port 443 and also make sure your firewall is allowing inbound traffic on that port.

Somewhere in your Apache config you need this,

```
Listen 443
```

On Debian (you don't mention your OS) it's in ports.conf like this,

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Also, don't forget you'll need to load the right module in Apache as well (how depends on your distribution).

And lastly, make sure you've opened port 443 on your firewall.

Comment: Also keep in mind that older distro releases (specifically mod_ssl) did not support SNI. Which appears to be what he wants to use.

Comment: haha, I did forget to open port 443 on router :D thx. your firewall remark reminded me :)

Answer (score -2):

First check in linux command,

```
# netstat -atnp | grep LISTEN
```

Result have to :

```
0.0.0.0:443
```

If not you must check config file.

At top config file, add:

```
Listen *:443
```

Then restart httpd.